# Añadí un marker a un punto X y aparece en ese punto y también en mi ubicación

Tags: swift, xcode

Cambie el diseño de un marcador en el mapView, pero al hacer esto me cambio el marcador de mi ubicación y no era lo que quería... Sólo quiero cambiar el marker de MIT, y el de mi ubicación dejarlo sólo con el marker azul normal que aparece en todos los mapas.

Aquí dejo algo de código que podría estar fallando.

```
mapView.register(MKMarkerAnnotationView.self,
                         forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
        let mitCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -41.471373559102965, longitude: -72.94215917587279)
        let mitAnnotation = SchoolAnnotation(coordinate: mitCoordinate, title: "MIT", subtitle: "mit - USA")

        mapView.addAnnotation(mitAnnotation)
        mapView.setRegion(mitAnnotation.region, animated: true)

extension BusinessViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if let schoolAnnotationView
            = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            schoolAnnotationView
            .animatesWhenAdded = true
            schoolAnnotationView
            .titleVisibility = .adaptive
            schoolAnnotationView
            .titleVisibility = .adaptive

            return schoolAnnotationView
        }

        return nil
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto, debería de funcionar...

```
extension BusinessViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
     if annotation != MKUserLocation {
        if let schoolAnnotationView
            = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            schoolAnnotationView
            .animatesWhenAdded = true
            schoolAnnotationView
            .titleVisibility = .adaptive
            schoolAnnotationView
            .titleVisibility = .adaptive

            return schoolAnnotationView
        }
      }
        return nil
    }
```